# Odd Generic Inheritance pattern

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

During some research, I ran into an inheritance pattern using generics I have not seen before.

http://thwadi.blogspot.ca/2013/07/using-protobuff-net-with-inheritance.html

```
public abstract class BaseClass<TClass> where TClass : BaseClass<TClass>
{
    //...
}
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass<DerivedClass>
{
    //...
}
```

Usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DerivedClass derivedReference = new DerivedClass();

    //this looks odd...
    BaseClass<DerivedClass> baseReference = derivedReference;

    //this doesn't work
    //BaseClass baseClass = derivedReference;

}
```

I was surprised that this even worked, I had to test it myself. I still can't understand why you would want to do this.

The only thing I could come up with, is preventing different derived classes from being stored in a collection together as their base class. This may be the reason, I guess I'm just curious to the application.

Comment: A good usage example is when you want to have chainable method calls in base class and derived class.

Comment: To make your last example work you would need a 3rd non generic class `public abstract class BaseClass {}` then the generic class would need to change to `public abstract class BaseClass<TClass> : BaseClass where TClass : BaseClass<TClass>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called the [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) it is often used to allow methods in the class to use the type of the derived class as a passed in or returned parameter.

For example, this is Clone method implemented so that only each layer needs to add it's own properties to the method as it goes down the chain.

```
public abstract class BaseClass<TClass> where TClass : BaseClass<TClass>, new()
{
    public int Foo {get;set;}

    public virtual TClass Clone()
    {
        var clone = new TClass();
        clone.Foo = this.Foo;
        return clone;
    }
}
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass<DerivedClass>
{
    public int Bar {get;set;}

    public override DerivedClass Clone()
    {
        var clone = base.Clone();
        clone.Bar = this.Bar;
        return clone;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DerivedClass derivedReference = new DerivedClass();

    DerivedClass clone = derivedReference.Clone();    
}
```

Comment: There's an edit suggesting ColoneInternal is a typo.

Comment: @BillWoodger just curious why was that not valid as an edit? (I've never tried that before)

Comment: @LukeCummings we don't know, yet, whether it was valid or not. I voted to reject. The way I look at it is, if the poster is still "active" on the site, leave a comment. If they're long-gone, attempt the edit, but beware that changing actual code can be tricky. Make your edit-comment really good.

Comment: @LukeCummings It's entirely subjective. I've voted to approve the edit, as it's *clearly* a typo and does not conflict with the author's answer in any way. Bill makes a good point, but in this case (such a small change), I think it's fine to make the edit yourself.

Comment: @LukeCummings your edit was fine and I approved it. I originally had two methods, Clone() and CloneInternal() but then decided to simplify the example but forgot to rename one of the calls.

Answer (score 3):

As an example of usage, suppose you want to implement some chainable builder methods on the base type and derived type like this:

```
var d = new DerivedClass();
d.SetPropertyA("some value").SetPropertyB(1);
```

While `SetPropertyA` belongs to base class and `SetPropertyB` belongs to derived class.

By implementing classes like below, when chaining methods, after calling `SetPropertyA` because the return value is of type `DerivedClass` you can call `SetPropertyB`:

```
public abstract class BaseClass<TClass> where TClass : BaseClass<TClass>
{
    public string A {get ; set; }
    public TClass SetPropertyA(string value)
    {
        this.A=value;
        return this as TClass;
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass<DerivedClass>
{
    public int B {get ; set; }
    public DerivedClass SetPropertyB(int value)
    {
        this.B=value;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then if you have some other derived classes, each of them can use the base `SetPropertyA` knowing the return value is of type of itself.