# Self-referenced generic parameter

Tags: c#, .net, generics, typing

For example I have the following classes:

1.

```cs
class MyClass1
{
    public MyClass1 Method()
    {
        ...
        return new MyClass1();
    }
}

class MyClass2
{
    public MyClass2 Method()
    {
        ...
        return new MyClass2();
    }
}
```

The methods have the same bodies that's why I want to extract the code and re-use.

2.

```cs
abstract class MyClass
{

    protected void Method()
    {
        ...
    }
}

class MyClass1 : MyClass
{

    public MyClass1 Method()
    {
        base.Method();
        return new MyClass1();
    }
}

class MyClass2 : MyClass
{
    public MyClass2 Method()
    {
        base.Method();
        return new MyClass2();
    }
}
```

However since there are a lot of such methods it will be better to move the methods into the base class `MyClass` at all:

3.

```cs
abstract class MyClass<T>: where T : MyClass<T>
{
    protected abstract T Create();

    public T Method()
    {
        ...
        return Create();
    }
}

class MyClass1 : MyClass<MyClass1>
{
    protected override MyClass1 Create() => new MyClass1();
}

class MyClass2 : MyClass<MyClass2>
{
    protected override MyClass2 Create() => new MyClass2();
}
```

It works fine but the contract looks too weird. Of course, I can extract something like `IMyInterface` and return it instead of the class. However I have to preserve the original contract because it contains specific methods as well.

**Upd:** So, the weird thing is in bold - class **MyClass1**: MyClass<**MyClass1**>

Comment: _“However I have to preserve the original contract”_ What do you mean with that?

Comment: Do you need `T` to be `MyClass<T>`, or would `T` suffice with `Create` simply returning a `MyClass<T>`?

Comment: @poke MyClass1 and MyClass2 as return type

Comment: @John MyClass<T> is not enough because MyClass1 and MyClass2 contain other methods as well. The base class MyClass<T> does not contain them

Comment: How is having the generic `MyClass<T>` then not working for you? I don’t understand why the `T Method()` on the base does not work for you.

Comment: @poke "It works fine but the contract looks too weird"

Comment: But if you look at it from the perspective of `MyClass1` or `MyClass2`, the contract should look the same as your original code.

Comment: Does `Create() => new MyClass1();` represent actual code? Or is that just an idea of what's done?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto If you want to suggest me `T: new()` constraint, don't do it. The question is about other things. Let's imagine MyClass1/2 doesn't have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are after then

Comment: I see downvotes. Please tell me what should be explained deeper?

Comment: `Foo : Thing<Foo>` is a fairly common pattern where `Thing<T>` needs to return instances of its subclass. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @canton7 could you provide some links describing the pattern and post it as answer? Maybe there are some usages in the standard libraries etc...

Comment: I don't have any links to hand, and I'm not aware of any instances in the BCL, but it's something I've come across a lot professionally and on IRC.

Comment: As canton7 wrote, It is a fairly common pattern. Please note, however, that it's not very type safe - nothing is stopping you from declaring `class Foo : Thing<Bar>`... even if you add a generic constraint : `class Thing<T> where T : Thing`, you can still do `class Foo: Thing<SomeUnrelatedClassDerivedFromThing>`.

Comment: [Odd Generic Inheritance pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34213055/3110834)

Comment: [Recursive constraints: What does DBase<T> : where T : DBase<T> mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53983914/3110834)

Comment: I'm not sure what do you expect as answer in this post, but you will find some useful ideas in the linked posts.

Comment: Are you talking about [Singleton](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx)?

Comment: The pattern name is **Curiously recurring template pattern**. You can search the pattern name and find some articles like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), [this one](https://zpbappi.com/curiously-recurring-template-pattern-in-csharp/) or [this one](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/215586/ComponentModel-for-ASP-NET-MVC3) or [this one](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser/) which describe/encourage/discourage using the pattern.

Comment: @RezaAghaei thank you! Could you post it as an answer to give me a way to award the bounty?

Comment: @Serg046 Thanks for the offer, if I think I can add some values to the linked posts, or sharing a good summary, I'll do.

Answer (score 4):

This is the usual so-called self-type problem (you have `Method()` should return the same type as the object on which it was called). Your solution #3 looks a lot like F-bounded quantification. However, this is C#, not Java, so we can do a bit better using an extension class.

You can make sure those methods only get called on subclasses of `MyClass` by adding a `where T : MyClass` bound on `T`.

```
// Put all your shared methods in generic classes in here.
public static class MyMethods
{
    public static T Method<T>(this T x) where T : MyClass
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Your classes don't change much, except they won't need to mention `Method` (or the other shared methods) at all.

```
public abstract class MyClass
{
    ...
}

public class MyClass1 : MyClass
{
    ...
}

public class MyClass2 : MyClass
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is this new in `c#`: `public static T Method<T extends MyClass>(this T x)`? This is the first time if seen the use of `extends` keyword...

Comment: @IronGeek Nah, just me forgetting the concrete syntax of C#. Moved into a `where` clause. This time, I also checked everything compiles. Thanks for keeping me honest :)

Comment: It allows public access only. Private/protected of MyClass are not available.

Comment: @Serg046 Quite right. `protected` is the real problem here: these aren't real methods, so you will never be able to override them. If you intend to have all subclasses of `MyClass` in your project, `internal` just might work instead of `private`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it looks a little bit weird to have a method which only create.

Because you have a 2 classes MyClass1 and MyClass2 which have their specific different methods and only base method is common (which you put in base class) I think you can use Abstract factory pattern.

```
public class ClassFactory: IClassFactory
{
    public MyClass Create()
    {
         if (some condition)
              return new MyClass1;
         return new MyClass2;
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    protected string CommonLogic()
    {
         //common logic 
         return string;
    }

}

class MyClass1 : MyClass
{
    public object SpecificMethod()
    {
        CommonLogic();
        .....
    }

}

class MyClass2 : MyClass
{
    public object SpecificMethod2()
    {
        CommonLogic();
        .....
    }
}
```

In this case you won't have duplicated code and you will have some class which one will have responsibility about creating you classes and will know when and which class return. + You will easy use it IoC here.

I hope my answer will help you.

Comment: How can it help? What's the difference between my #2 and your suggestion? Anyway, thank you for your time and attempt.

Comment: Logic in #2 and my answer more less the same. Problem in your case only in responsibilities. You have 2 classes which are created by their self. in my case it is some another class which will decide how to create and it means it will be more flexible. Send all dependencies on top level is good practise. Now if you need to use my factory you need to add constructor dependency and after that create what you want. If you need to change logic how to create class, you will only create another implementation of factory and change setup of IoC container.

Comment: Or you can update how will you use this common method and we will find another solution or will keep yours.

Comment: I need MyClass1/MyClass2 contract. They have their specific methods. I cannot describe them by a single contract. `Of course, I can extract something like IMyInterface and return it instead of the class. However I have to preserve the original contract because it contains specific methods as well`.

Comment: abstract class MyClass
    {
        protected abstract MyClass Create();

        public MyClass Method()
        {
            return Create();
        }
    }
    class MyClass1 : MyClass
    {
        protected override MyClass Create() => new MyClass1();
    }
    class MyClass2 : MyClass
    {
        protected override MyClass Create() => new MyClass2();
    }

And everywhere where you need to get specific methods to do cast like `var mcl = myClass as MyClass1; mcl.SpecificMethod();` Or you want always know type of class without casting.

Comment: Casting? No, thanks. My options #2, #3 and your original suggestion are better.

Comment: Yes. 2, 3 and mine is better than casting :)

Answer (score 0):

There are some rare situations where a self-referencing type constraint may be needed, but I am not convinced that this is one of them.

It seems that you want to use the factory (Create) pattern and also have those factories return different concrete types. But at the same time you are saying that these concrete types all have something in common, specified by the base class.

The conventional approach would be to define the common features in an interface (IMyInterface as you suggested) and return that from the Create method. This would capture the polymorphic aspect of the concrete classes. Then the question is how to capture the other methods that are implemented in the concrete types. For this one can simply define additional interfaces that capture the various clusters of functionality implemented by more than one of the  concrete classes.

To the extent that there are any dribs and drabs of functionality left over after you've done that, I would say handle them by casting would be the easiest -- at that point the functionality would be unique to just one of the concrete classes. If you want to fly with your eyes closed you could use the 'dynamic' type instead of casting.

Also, normally the Create method is not defined in the object instances, in other words normally objects are not their own factories. Typically they are either static or in a separate factory classes. In the current situation a bit of reflection helps deal with the fact that you have multiple derived types. There are various ways to do this besides what I show below.

So … perhaps something like this:

```
public interface ICommonFunctionality
{
    void SomethingThatEveryoneCanDo();
    // ... other common functionality
}

public interface IAdditionalFunctionality1
{
    void SomethingThatAFewCanDo();
    // ... other special functionality
}
public interface IAdditionalFunctionality2
{
    void SomethingThatOthersCanDo();
    // ... other special functionality
}

public class MyClass : ICommonFunctionality
{
    static public ICommonFunctionality Create(Type derivedType)
    {
        if (!typeof(ICommonFunctionality).IsAssignableFrom(derivedType)) { throw new ArgumentException(); }
        return derivedType.CreateInstance() as ICommonFunctionality;
    }

    virtual public void SomethingThatEveryoneCanDo() { /* ... */  }
}

public class MyClass1 : MyClass, IAdditionalFunctionality1
{
    public void SomethingThatAFewCanDo() { /* ... */ }
}

public class MyClass2 : MyClass, IAdditionalFunctionality1, IAdditionalFunctionality2
{
    public void SomethingThatAFewCanDo() { /* ... */ }
    public void SomethingThatOthersCanDo() { /* ... */ }
}

public class MyClass3 : MyClass, IAdditionalFunctionality2
{
    public void SomethingThatOthersCanDo() { /* ... */ }
}

public static class TypeHelpers
{
    public static object CreateInstance(this Type type, bool required = true)
    {
        System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo ctor = type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
        if (required && ctor == null) { throw new InvalidOperationException("Missing required constructor."); }
        return ctor?.Invoke(null);
    }
}
```

P.S. I have made the base class method virtual, this is pretty much optional depending on your situation.

Comment: This answer is very thick with terminology and thin on actual code. How exactly would you implement this for OP's `MyClass`, `MyClass1`, `MyClass2`, and `Method`? I don't see how this is any more than a partial description of the OP's 3rd attempt.